# JavaScript SOAP Client receives null

Tags: javascript, soap, xsd, wsdl

I'm running into some problems, with the JavaScript SOAP Client.

I tried to pass the following parameters:

```
var url = "http://mywebservice/ws";
var pl = new SOAPClientParameters();
pl.add("name1", "Hans");
pl.add("name2", "Bernd");
SOAPClient.invoke(url, "hello", pl, true, HelloWorld_callBack);
```

The server- side code, that should answer my request looks like this:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name1") String txt,@WebParam(name= "name2") String strInput2)
{
    String strMethode = "hello";
    return "Hello " + txt + " and " + strInput2 + " !";
}
```

The connection is running fine, but the Callback method prints

> Hello null and null !

If I try the same from C# or Java it works fine, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have done a mistake in client line, 
SOAPClient.invoke(url, "hello", pl, true, HelloWorld_callBack);
Check [this](http://www.guru4.net/articoli/javascript-soap-client/demo/en.aspx)